# Using SharePoint Workflow to call a Java class

Tags: workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, file

Is it possible to create a workflow which call a Java class?

My main goal is to select a file and press a button in SharePoint document library which transfers this file to a Java class where I can do some stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 2013, you can expose your Java class in a web service, and call that from your workflow. That's the only way I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes it's 2013 and is there any way you can show me a example of it on SharePoint Designer 2013

Comment: I can't help you write a Java web service, but here's how you'd consume it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx